# Trigger with multipe IF conditions doesn't trigger

Tags: mysql-5.7

I am trying to update the table `latest_activities` with the latest activity a employee had.

An activity has multiple conditions to be considered as the latest activity.

The reason why I don't do a JOIN to get the latest activity from the table `activity` is because of performance and a sub-optimal database design I cannot change.

This is the trigger I have made. It doesn't add any records to `latest_activities`. I suspect the problem is that there are a difference on [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) and [IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html). Also I am not sure that my `REPLACE INTO` is correct

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_latest_activity
    AFTER INSERT ON activity
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.log = 0
        AND (NEW.type = 'hired'
        OR (NEW.type = 'note'
        AND JSON_VALID(NEW.data) = 1
        AND NEW.data->>'$.status' = 1))
    THEN
        REPLACE INTO
            latest_activities (employee_id, activity_id)
        SELECT
            pivot.employee_id AS employee_id,
            pivot.activity_id AS activity_id
        FROM
            pivot
        WHERE
            pivot.activity_id = NEW.id
            AND pivot.type LIKE '%Employee';
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**UPDATE**

After debugging (thanks to @akina) I found that `NEW.id` for some reason isn't working when used in the `REPLACE INTO` statement `pivot.activity_id = NEW.id`. Hard-coding the value will work, so the query is correct.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

The problem was obvious when I took a step back. Trigger should be on the `pivot` table because the relationship is first created there AFTER the data has been inserted into the `activity` table *facepalm*.

Comment: Create service table. Add statements which save all values and separate conditions results into it. Then analyse trigger execution flow.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean with service table?

Comment: For what it's worth, this is exactly why people discourage use of triggers; they're opaque and hard to debug.  For this usage, I'd be tempted to create a much simpler trigger that just mirrors the entire row into a table every time it's changed.  That would give you a complete change history of the row, from which you could create a query (or a view) to show only the latest activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug your trigger.

Create service table.

```
CREATE TABLE service (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                      step INT,
                      data TEXT,
                      dt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Add tracing info save (example code).

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_latest_activity
    AFTER INSERT ON activity
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO service (step, data) VALUES (1, NEW.log);
    INSERT INTO service (step, data) VALUES (2, NEW.log = 0);
    INSERT INTO service (step, data) VALUES (3, NEW.type);
    INSERT INTO service (step, data) VALUES (4, NEW.data);
    INSERT INTO service (step, data) VALUES (5, JSON_VALID(NEW.data));
    INSERT INTO service (step, data) VALUES (6, NEW.data->>'$.status');
    INSERT INTO service (step, data) VALUES (7, NEW.log = 0
                                                AND (NEW.type = 'hired'
                                                OR (NEW.type = 'note'
                                                    AND JSON_VALID(NEW.data) = 1
                                                    AND NEW.data->>'$.status' = 1)));
    IF NEW.log = 0
        AND (NEW.type = 'hired'
        OR (NEW.type = 'note'
        AND JSON_VALID(NEW.data) = 1
        AND NEW.data->>'$.status' = 1))
    THEN
        INSERT INTO service (step, data) VALUES (8, 'Execute THEN branch');
        REPLACE INTO
            latest_activities (employee_id, activity_id)
        SELECT
            pivot.employee_id AS employee_id,
            pivot.activity_id AS activity_id
        FROM
            pivot
        WHERE
            pivot.activity_id = NEW.id
            AND pivot.type LIKE '%Employee';
    END IF;
END
```

Insert record which must (as you think) to perform the action.

Analyse the info in service table.

Comment: +1 for that way of debugging. It got me on the right track